# How to actively take data being written to a csv file and show it in google sheets?

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, raspberry-pi

I have all the code to take data from my *sense hat* and write it to a file. I want that data to be collected by the *sense hat*, and in the simplest way be able to view that CSV file on my phone.

I'm wondering if I can have my information from the CSV file and transfer it to google sheets effectively every 60 seconds when the *sense hat* takes data again.

I'm trying to do this with google sheets, but I have also explored Flask. That might be too difficult for me, but I'm open to ideas.

Here is the code to retrieve the data and write it to the CSV file

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


FILENAME = ""
#every other 10, yes 20, no, 30, yes ECT.
WRITE_FREQUENCY = 2
TEMP = True
HUMIDITY = True
PRESSURE = True
#time between intervals
DELAY=10


#all headers, where to append
def file_setup(filename):
    header = []
    if TEMP:
        header.append("temp")
    if HUMIDITY:
        header.append("humidity")
    if PRESSURE:
        header.append("pressure")
    header.append("timestamp")
    
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(",".join(str(value) for value in header)+ "\n")
        
#log data
def log_data():
    output_string = ",".join(str(value) for value in sense_data)
    batch_data.append(output_string)
    
def get_sense_data():
    sense_data=[]
    
    if TEMP:
        sense_data.append(sense.get_temperature())
        
    if HUMIDITY:
        sense_data.append(sense.get_pressure())
    
    if PRESSURE:
        sense_data.append(sense.get_pressure())
        
    sense_data.append(datetime.now())
    
    return sense_data

#works frequency n delay
def timed_log():
    while True:
        log_data()
        sleep(DELAY)
        
sense = SenseHat()
batch_data= []


#filename stuff
if FILENAME == "":
    filename = "SenseLog-"+str(datetime.now())+".csv"
else:
    filename = FILENAME+"-"+str(datetime.now())+".csv"
    
file_setup(filename)


#tells me its writing between delays
if DELAY > 0:
    sense_data = get_sense_data()
    Thread(target= timed_log).start()
    
while True:
    sense_data = get_sense_data()
    
    if DELAY == 0:
        log_data()
        
    if len(batch_data) >= WRITE_FREQUENCY:
        print("Writing to file..")
        with open(filename,"a") as f:
            for line in batch_data:
                f.write(line + "\n")
            batch_data = []
```

Comment: The code is so poorly formatted it is difficult to see what it is doing. I could make some guesses about what it should look like, but I would rather not. Clean up the formatting to get something understandable. Suggestion use the *``` <code> ```* method to format code block.

Comment: Did I fix it? Or no?

Comment: Yes that is better. Does this code produce the CSV you want?

Comment: Another suggestion would be to look at Adafruit [IO](https://io.adafruit.com/).